# Qt Antialiasing Issue on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cmake, antialiasing

I'm trying to build a Qt-based app on OSX (using CMake), but all the widgets (and text) that I'm creating look terrible.

For example, here is a screenshot of the checkbox and magnification text within the System Preferences app:

[image: looking_good]

and here is a sample checkbox and text from my app:

[image: poop]

My Info.plist file contains

`<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
    <string>True</string>`

but this doesn't seem to have an effect.  I've also tried setting the render hint for fonts, but again, nothing changes. Is there something special that needs to be done to get simple things like checkboxes to render well on OSX when using Qt?

Comment: What version of Qt do you use? It is not possible to fix it in Qt4 on retina displays :). I spent a lot of time with dpi scaling issues on retina.

Comment: Qt 5.3. Any experience with Qt5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the Info.plist tweak ended up being the correct fix, but OSX caches the .plist files. Deleting the entire generated bundle (including the .plist) fixed the issue. Hooray for good looking checkboxes.